# How can i implement a gallery(deprecated) type view using horizontal scroll view with view recycling

Tags: android, view, horizontalscrollview

I can not use android gallery view since it is deprecated. I need to implement it using horizontal scroll view. but there is no view recycling ability default. can any one suggest how can I implement it with view recycling functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should Go with `ViewPager`. i.e `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`

1) It Help you to get Horizontal Scroll Swipe

2) It also Recycle the View as you wanted

Follow this tutorial

[Here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/)

Hope this is HelpFul...